# "psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused" error when bootstrapping

Tags: juju, maas

After the successful import of the ssh keypairs, the bootstrap generates this error.

Can anyone help me?

```
connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have tried:

- Ensuring PostgreSQL is installed and running via: 'sudo service postgresql start`

This errors appears how i running 'sudo apt-get update'.

Comment: What program are you referring to?

Comment: In trying install maas as a service. I'm newbie! This occurs. I believe my proxy or other config is generate this error or my network config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like postgres is not running or not installed.

Try:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but continuous get the same error.

Comment: The error get in the if i apply Updates. Maybe my configuration port are broken or config with error. It's various days I seek help, and don't understand whats happening with the ssh key.

Comment: @SidineyRodrigues Can you add anymore information to your question? Also please click the green check on this answer to mark it as unanswered, that way it can get more attention, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If the server is running and you still get the error, you must configure Postgres to accept connections from other IPs. In order to do so, locate the `postgresql.conf` file.

Look for `listen_addresses` property and replace `localhost` with the choice of your IPs separated by comma OR `*` to accept connections from any IP.

Restart the postgresql server. You should be good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Before running you must check that u have placed your file in a proper location.
eg. If you are using vagrant and virtual box then you must keep this file in a vagrant folder.

Comment: I gave up trying to set up